# How can I prove the following operator is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let us have the following operator $T : C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ by the formula 
$$Tx(t)=\int \limits _a ^t x(τ)\ \Bbb dτ$$ 
How can I prove $T$ is a continuous operator? The space $C[a,b]$ is equipped with the norm $\| x \| = \max \limits _{t \in [a,b]} |x(t)|$.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you write down the definition of a continuous operator?

Answer (score 2):

Given $x,y \in C[a,b]$ and $t\in [a,b]$,

$$Tx(t) - Ty(t) = \int_a^t [x(\tau) - y(\tau)]\, d\tau.$$

So

$$|Tx(t) - Ty(t)| \le \int_a^t |x(\tau) - y(\tau)|\, d\tau \le \int_a^b |x(\tau) - y(\tau)|\, d\tau \le (b - a)\max_{\tau \in [a,b]} |x(\tau) - y(\tau)|$$

for all $t \in [a,b]$, which implies

$$\max_{t\in [a,b]} |Tx(t) - Ty(t)| \le (b - a) \max_{\tau \in [a,b]} |x(\tau) - y(\tau)|.$$

That is,

$$\|Tx - Ty\|_{C[a,b]} \le (b - a) \|x - y\|_{C[a,b]}.$$

Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, it follows that $T$ is continuous (in fact, Lipschitz continuous).